# Get persian information from android Geocoder

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, geolocation, google-geocoder

I'm trying to get Persian information from android [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), i mean i pass latitude and longitude and i want to get name of the city in Persian, but there is no locale to get those info in Persian.
I can see that in [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) google suggests location names in Persian, but there's no locale to set for the Geocoder.
Does anybody know a way to get those info in Persian?

Comment: Check if its implemented: `The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.` Alternatively look at Google Places API: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass your desire locale in constructor:

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getActivity(), new Locale("fa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** : for [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) package :

```
 List<Placemark> _placemarks = 
     await placemarkFromCoordinates(
         latitude,
         longitude,
         localeIdentifier: "fa-IR"
     );
```